# How to suppress printing exceptions' names and their backtrace in Ruby / RoR app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want Ruby on Rails app output logs only in JSON so it's edible for most log processing tools. I'm using Lograge for that. However, when there is an exception raised, not only JSON logline is shown, but also the exception's name and its backtrace. This breaks JSON parsing.

Example of an output:

```
{"method":"GET","path":"/raise_exception_path","format":"html","controller":"ApplicationController","action":"raise_exception_path","status":500,"error":"RuntimeError: exception is raised error","duration":46.0,"view":0.37,"db":0.0,"exception":["RuntimeError","exception is raised"],"exception_object":"exception is raised ","@timestamp":"2019-07-03T08:18:16.979Z","@version":"1","message":"[500] GET /version (ApplicationController#version)"}

RuntimeError (exception is raised):

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6:in `version'
```

I've tried Rails' log silencers/filters, but they'd only deal with the backtrace - not the exception name itself. A line `RuntimeError (exception is raised):` is still printed to the console.

Also, I thought maybe it's just enough to redirect STDERR to `/dev/null`, but apparently these exceptions and their backtrace are printed to STDOUT.

My application configuration:

```
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    config.lograge.enabled = true
    config.lograge.base_controller_class = 'ActionController::API'
    config.lograge.formatter = Lograge::Formatters::Logstash.new

    config.lograge.custom_options = lambda do |event|
      {
        exception: event.payload[:exception], # ["ExceptionClass", "the message"]
        exception_object: event.payload[:exception_object] # the exception instance
      }
    end
    $stderr.reopen("/dev/null", "w")
```

The expected result would be that on production I have a stream of JSON-only loglines, ideally printed to STDOUT, without any exceptions or stacktraces.

```
{"method":"GET","path":"/","format":"html","controller":"TimezoneController","action":"timezone","status":200,"duration":11.56,"view":2.0,"db":0.0,"exception":null,"exception_object":null,"@timestamp":"2019-07-03T08:18:13.954Z","@version":"1","message":"[200] GET / (TimezoneController#timezone)"}
{"method":"GET","path":"/version","format":"html","controller":"ApplicationController","action":"version","status":500,"error":"RuntimeError: earth is flat error","duration":46.0,"view":0.37,"db":0.0,"exception":["RuntimeError","earth is flat error"],"exception_object":"earth is flat error","@timestamp":"2019-07-03T08:18:16.979Z","@version":"1","message":"[500] GET /version (ApplicationController#version)"}
{"method":"GET","path":"/","format":"html","controller":"TimezoneController","action":"timezone","status":200,"duration":11.56,"view":2.0,"db":0.0,"exception":null,"exception_object":null,"@timestamp":"2019-07-03T08:18:13.954Z","@version":"1","message":"[200] GET / (TimezoneController#timezone)"}
{"method":"GET","path":"/version","format":"html","controller":"ApplicationController","action":"version","status":500,"error":"RuntimeError: earth is flat error","duration":46.0,"view":0.37,"db":0.0,"exception":["RuntimeError","earth is flat error"],"exception_object":"earth is flat error","@timestamp":"2019-07-03T08:18:16.979Z","@version":"1","message":"[500] GET /version (ApplicationController#version)"}
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @MatejChrenko unfortunately not really, the only workaround I came up with is I'm deleting all the lines that do not start with `{` with grep. What's you're use case? For me I essentially wanted to have a clear, JSON output in STDOUT that I could then handle with Kubernetes and then Grafana/ELK stack

Comment: I have the same usecase. Only difference is I need it for splunk. Which still means json in STDOUT. What I need extra is to add whole backtrace (that non json lines) into that json.